# Adding Metadata to Uploaded Image Firebase/Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I am able to upload a corresponding image through the call:

```
var uploadTask = firebase_ref.putStream(stream)
```

I want to add metadata to the uploaded image, so I want to do this inside the putStream call:

```
var uploadTask = firebase_ref.putStream(stream, metadata)
```

Now the issue is I am able to import StorageMetadata with this import:

```
import com.google.firebase.storage.*
```

I am able to create a StorageMetadata object like:

```
var metadata = StorageMetadata()
```

I go to adjust a simple name parameter for the metadata as:

```
metadata.name = "something"
```

**ERROR:
val cannot be reassigned**

I have looked at this reference:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#kotlin+ktx_5

They suggest doing:

```
var metadata = storageMetadata {
    contentType = "image/jpg"
}
```

**ERROR: 
unresolved reference storageMetadata**

What is the best way to adjust a simple StorageMetadata and pass it into putStream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kotlin+KTX sample it's showing depends on adding the [Cloud Storage for Firebase KTX library](https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/docs/ktx/storage/) to your dependencies (that's what the "KTX" is telling you).  After you do that, you will have the [storageMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/ktx/package-summary#storageMetadata(kotlin.Function1)) builder available in your code as shown in the documentation.  If you want to use that, be sure to follow the documentation a linked here.  You will add a dependency that looks like this:

```
// See maven.google.com for the latest versions
// This library transitively includes the firebase-storage library
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:$VERSION'
```

If you don't want to use the KTX library, you can work with the metadata object using the [StorageMetadata.Builder](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata.Builder) object as shown in the Java sample.  [StorageMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageMetadata) objects are immutable (notice there are no setters in that class), so you can't create one and just modify it - you have to build one using the provided builder.

Comment: Thanks, this was the issue. Added: implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx:19.1.1'